# want to start activity after completion of animation of imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to `rotate` `imageview` and then I want to start `activity` onClick of `imageview` but the problem is that android system doesn't give the time to complete the `animation` and launching the activity. So how can I show the animation completely and then calling the activity.
This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromDegrees="-7"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="7" />
```

And this  code:

```
      public void onImageViewClicked(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.viewstock:
                Animation shakeV = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,     R.anim.shake);
                view.startAnimation(shakeV);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 12);
                break;
            case R.id.about:
                Animation shakeA = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,     R.anim.shake1);


                 view.startAnimation(shakeA);
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, My guessing was right. Use for **shakeA, shakeV**

```
shakeA.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
```

`@Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Start your activity here.
            startActivity(aboutIntent); // Here you go.

        }
    })`

Comment: Do not insert two answers. Edit the first answer please.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. The time I was writing the example I guess you already answered. Thanks again for providing the example.

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide your code snippet to support your question. So it would be much easier to know how you are handling the animation.

For now I will assume that you are using standard Animation. If that is the case use `Animation.AnimationListener` to listen `onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)`. There you start your activity.

For more check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that it's better to set a duration for start activity

```
    @Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(aboutIntent); 
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```