# Start Activity after animation finishes

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this code

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent.putExtra("chapter", 1);
            b1.startAnimation(animZoom1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
```

the method runs all lines in one time, the animation duration is 1.5 seconds but the `Activity` runs in less than 0.5 seconds 
I just want to run `StartActiviy(intenet);` after the animation ends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

in [onAnimationEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)) start your `Activity` with the `Intent`

I just picked the first one from a quick search but, [this answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436368/want-to-start-activity-after-completion-of-animation-of-imageview). You can also search and find many many many more examples.