# Android open Image onclick like Whatsapp Profile Picture

Tags: android, animation, imageview, fragment, toolbar

I have a collapsing toolbar with ImageView inside, when the image is clicked I want to enlarge it with an animation and go to another "activity" like whatsapp, telegram and a lot of other apps which allow user to click the profile photo of friends.

This will allow the user to see the image in the center of the screen and save or share the picture.

I had a look of Zooming a View http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html but it isn't enough and I have lag during the animation. (I used the same code provided)

Answer (score 13):

I think your key is shared element transition. You can follow this [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-android-shared-element-transition-ac36952a4a4#.eo0ug19hk)

Give the same transition name to both of the views which are in different activities.
`android:transitionName="@string/transition_string"`

Add this bundle where you start the zoomed activity

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, view, view.getTransitionName()).toBundle();
            startActivity(intent,bundle);
```

And don't forget to add this line to your activity's style

```
<!-- Add this line -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

Comment: @opsenes do you have anything for fragments?

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev check this out 
https://medium.com/google-developers/fragment-transitions-ea2726c3f36f

Comment: Superb @opsenes

Answer (score 9):

You may want to look at Google's documentation on zooming a view [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

Basically the way they tell you to go about this is by creating an imagebutton that will display the smaller image, that when clicked will play an animation, and at the end reveal an imageview with the full sized image in it.

The layout they give as an example is this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of
         the images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire
         screen. To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated
         from the bounds of the thumbnail button above, to its final laid-out
         bounds.
         -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" /></FrameLayout>
```

Then you can set up the animation like this:

```
public class ZoomActivity extends FragmentActivity {
// Hold a reference to the current animator,
// so that it can be canceled mid-way.
private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

// The system "short" animation time duration, in milliseconds. This
// duration is ideal for subtle animations or animations that occur
// very frequently.
private int mShortAnimationDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

    // Hook up clicks on the thumbnail views.

    final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
}}
```

There are several more steps, but at this point I'm literally copy and pasting from their documentation. You really should go read up on it. If you have any questions let me know!

Comment: As you said you just copy and pasted their documentation, as I said I already had a look but I don't know how to create another "fragment" or "activity" after the user click the button

Comment: Ahh, well in that case you should set an animationListener that calls StartActivity in the onAnimationEnd method. If you have created the activity that you want to launch at the end of the animation you just need to use the same code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12436581/4463041)
Also, sorry for repeating your link. I'm not sure how I missed that.